# Gerrit trigger trouble with ref-update

Tags: jenkins, gerrit, gerrit-trigger

Gerrit Trigger 2.32.0

I configuration "Trigger on"    with "Ref Updated" to support push event.But I find when I reply on the pathset with comment, Ref Updated is triggered. Param GERRIT_REFNAME is refs/changes/96/996/meta.
I don't know how to filtered it to make only push event triggered by "Ref Updated" event.

Comment: Why are you not using the "Patchset Created" event?

Comment: Yeah,Patchset Created is selected. Event is only for person who need review with patch. Some gerrit user need trigger jenkins's flow with push event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to filter out refs you're not interested in. The `REG_EXP` comparison type seems to use Java's [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), which supports negative lookaheads.

Example expression which doesn't match anything that starts with "refs/": `^(?!refs/).*$`.

Full example for trigger setup (using a scripted pipeline):

```
properties([
        pipelineTriggers([
                [
                        $class         : 'GerritTrigger',
                        gerritProjects : [
                                [
                                        $class     : 'GerritProject',
                                        compareType: 'PLAIN',
                                        pattern    : 'my-gerrit-project',
                                        branches   : [
                                                [
                                                        $class     : 'Branch',
                                                        compareType: 'REG_EXP',
                                                        // does not start with "refs/"
                                                        pattern    : '^(?!refs/).*$'
                                                ]
                                        ]
                                ]
                        ],
                        triggerOnEvents: [
                                [
                                        $class: 'PluginPatchsetCreatedEvent'
                                ],
                                [
                                        $class: 'PluginRefUpdatedEvent'
                                ]
                        ]
                ]
        ])
])
```

(I know this is more than 2 years late, but I just ran into this issue, so maybe it helps someone.)